# Dart js interop with D3

Tags: d3.js, dart

I am trying to integrate D3 with dart: My code to this point is as follows:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
   js.scoped(() {
     var dee3 = js.context.d3; 
     var dataset = js.array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ]);
     dee3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

  });
```

Whenever I run this in dartium I get the following exception:
Exception: A function must be converted to a Callback before it can be serialized. 
How can I convert the anonymous function(d) to a callback?

Comment: Remember to accept the correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

As *package:js > 0.2.0* `Callback` and `js.scoped` are no longer needed.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  var dee3 = js.context.d3; 
  var dataset = js.array([ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ]);
  dee3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text((d, i, context) => d);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, these lines give me the error message "The name 'context' is being referenced through the prefix 'js', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix."

Comment: Hi Alexandre Ardhuin can I use d3.js inside Flutter applications? and how?